# Выражение должно иметь константное значение C++ (помогите пофиксить ошибку)

Tags: c++, графы

Выдает ошибку: "выражение должно иметь константное значение". Как можно пофиксить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

struct {
    char sign;
    std::vector<bool> edges;
} typedef Graph;

/*
     * Граф, содержащий Эйлеров цикл
    10
    a b c d e f g h i j
    0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
    1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
    1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
    0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
    1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
    1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1
    0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
    0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
    0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
    0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
    */

    /*
         * 1. Найти и вывести эйлеров цикл в графе.
         *
         * Эйлеров путь (эйлерова цепь) в графе — это путь,
         * проходящий по всем рёбрам графа и притом только
         * по одному разу.
         *
         * Эйлеров путь в графе существует тогда и только тогда,
         * когда граф связный и содержит не более двух вершин
         * нечётной степени.
         *
         * 2. Реализовать обход графа в ширину. +
         * */

         // http://graphonline.ru/?graph=HDumlQSPEidmrFMJ

void euler_path(std::vector<std::vector<bool>>& graph,
    std::vector<char>& nodes);

void breadth_first_traversal(std::vector<std::vector<bool>>& graph,
    std::vector<char>& nodes);

int main() {
    std::cout << "=== Практическая 5 ===" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "===   Вариант 28   ===" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Граф создан на основе списка ребер." << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    int option;
    std::cout << "Ввести граф (1) или использовать граф по умолчанию (2): ";
    std::cin >> option;

    std::vector<char> nodes;
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> graph;

    // создание графи на основе ввода с клавиатуры
    if (option == 1) {
        int n;
        char name;
        std::cout << "Кол-во вершин в графе: ";
        std::cin >> n;
        std::cout << "Названия вершин: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            std::cin >> name;
            nodes.push_back(name);
        }
        std::cout << "Введите матрицу смежности: " << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            std::vector<bool> tmp;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                int r;
                std::cin >> r;
                tmp.push_back(r);
            }
            graph.push_back(tmp);
            tmp.clear();
        }
    }
    // граф, определнный в варинте
    if (option == 2) {
        nodes = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k' };
        graph = {
            //     a  b  c  d  f  g  h  i  j  k
            /*a*/ {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            /*b*/ {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            /*c*/ {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
            /*d*/ {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
            /*f*/ {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            /*g*/ {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            /*h*/ {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1},
            /*i*/ {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
            /*j*/ {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
            /*k*/ {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0} };
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "=== Эйлеров путь ===" << std::endl;
    euler_path(graph, nodes);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "=== Обход в ширину ===" << std::endl;
    breadth_first_traversal(graph, nodes);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

void euler_path(std::vector<std::vector<bool>>& graph, std::vector<char>& nodes) {
    // Проверяю, является ли граф связным
    for (std::vector<bool>& vertex : graph) {
        if (std::count(vertex.begin(), vertex.end(), 1) == 0) {
            std::cout << "Граф не содержит Эйлеров цикл (граф несвязный)"
                << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Проверяю, содержит ли граф вершины с нечетной степенью
    int count = 0;
    for (std::vector<bool>& vertex : graph) {
        if (std::count(vertex.begin(), vertex.end(), true) % 2 == 1) {
            count++;
        }
        if (count > 2) {
            std::cout << "В графе более 2-х вершин с нечетной степенью ==> "
                << std::endl
                << " ==> граф не содержит эйлеров путь." << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Создаю обертку над графом для простоты вывода пути на экран
    std::vector<Graph> g_vec(graph.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < graph.size(); ++i) {
        g_vec[i].sign = nodes.at(i);
        g_vec[i].edges = graph.at(i);
    }

    // Если граф полуэйлеровый, то путь надо
    // начинать с вершины с нечетной степенью
    std::stack<Graph*> stack;
    std::vector<char> result;

    // Кладу первую попавшуюся
    // вершину нечетной степени в стек
    size_t idx_of_start =
        std::distance(graph.begin(),
            std::find_if(
                graph.begin(),
                graph.end(),
                [](const std::vector<bool>& vertex) {
                    return std::count(vertex.begin(), vertex.end(), true) % 2;
                }));

    stack.push(&g_vec.at((idx_of_start != g_vec.size()) ? idx_of_start : 0));

    while (!stack.empty()) {
        Graph* V = stack.top();
        bool found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); ++i) {
            if (V->edges.at(i)) {
                found = true;
                // Кладу другой конец этой вершины в стек
                stack.push(&g_vec.at(i));
                // Удаляю ребро, которое было пройдено
                V->edges.at(i) = false;
                g_vec.at(i).edges[std::distance(g_vec.begin(),
                    std::find_if(g_vec.begin(), g_vec.end(),
                        [&V](const Graph& G) {
                            return G.sign == V->sign;
                        }))] = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            stack.pop();
            result.push_back(V->sign);
        }
    }

    std::for_each(result.begin(),
        result.end() - 1,
        [](const char& vertex) {
            std::cout << vertex << " --- ";
        });
    std::cout << *(result.end() - 1) << std::endl;
}

void breadth_first_traversal(std::vector<std::vector<bool>>& graph,
     std::vector<char>& nodes) {

    bool visited[nodes.size()];

    std::queue<std::vector<bool>> queue;
    queue.push(graph.at(0));
    visited[0] = true;
    std::cout << nodes.at(0) << " ";

    while (!queue.empty()) {
        std::vector<bool> vertex = queue.front();
        queue.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < vertex.size(); ++i) {
            if (vertex.at(i) && !visited[i]) {
                std::cout << nodes.at(i) << " ";
                queue.push(graph.at(i));
                visited[i] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В С++ для создания массива его размер должен быть известен во время компиляции. Используйте `vector`.

Comment: Где я должен указать размер вектора, в какой строке?

Comment: Вместо массива, вызвавшего ошибку, используйте вектор.

Comment: Так я и так использую вектор

Comment: `bool visited[nodes.size()];` Это не вектор.

Comment: А что написать, чтобы это стало вектором?

Comment: Да вы вообще писали эту программу или нет?!! `std::vector<bool> tmp;` — и вы не знаете как писать вектор?!!

Comment: Писал, это уже не важно. Я бы хотел, чтобы вы мне помогли как можно скорее, а не тратили время друг-друга

Comment: Вам сюда: http://www.reshaem.net/

Comment: Помогают тем, кто сам себе помогает. Вы, видимо, не поняли суть данного сайта.

Comment: std::vector<bool> visited[nodes.size()]; 
Это не помогает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## std::vector visited(nodes.size());

Теперь понятно? Ну попытайтесь **думать**...

Comment: Спасибо огромное!